# ¿Como mostrar la fecha y hora almacenada en SQL?

Tags: sql-server

tengo un pequeño problema, a lo mejor es de lo mas sencillo tengo una consulta lo cual me muestra fecha y hora que ya esta almacenada en BD, pero siempre me muestra la misma hora en todas 2018-10-05 **12:46:03.000** la hora si se guarda bien la consulta es la siguiente:

```
protected function obtenerNotas(Request $request){
        return response()->json(
            DB::table('tblNotas as n')
                ->select('n.idNota','n.Observacion as Nota','n.claveAccion as ClaveAccion','uu.Nombre as Verificador','u.Nombre as Usuario',
                DB::raw("(CONCAT(DAY(Fecha),'/',MONTH(Fecha),'/',YEAR(Fecha),' ',SUBSTRING('2018-10-05 12:46:03.000',CHARINDEX(' ','2018-10-05 12:46:03.000'),9))) AS Fecha"))
                ->join('tblApoyoAcciones as aa','aa.ClaveAccionApoyo','n.claveAccion')
                ->join('tblUsuarios as u','u.idUser','n.idUsuario')
                ->join('tblUsuarios as uu','uu.idUser','n.idUsuario')
                ->where('aa.ClaveAccionApoyo',$request->claveAccion)
                ->orderBy('Fecha','DESC')

                ->get()
        );
    }
```

Resultado:

**30/11/2018 12:46:03**

**20/11/2018 12:46:03**

**10/11/2018 12:46:03**

Ojala me puedan ayudar :( se los agradecería.

Comment: No queda claro cuál es el resultado que esperas =/ , ya que en la función `SUBSTRING` estas indicando la fecha y hora _en duro_

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera esque si me muestra la hora y fecha pero siempre me muestra la hora 12:46:03 en todos lo registros aunque en la base de datos este guardada correctamente no se si sea la forma en como mando la consulta

Comment: Debe ser por lo que te menciono.. en esta linea `raw("(CONCAT(DAY(Fecha),'/',MONTH(Fecha),'/',YEAR(Fecha),' ',SUBSTRING('2018-10-05 12:46:03.000',CHARINDEX(' ','2018-10-05 12:46:03.000'),9))) AS Fecha"))` estas realizando un substring y ahi especificas en duro la hora **12:46:03.000**

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera lo indico asi pero ya no me muestra la hora DB::raw("(CONCAT(DAY(Fecha),'/',MONTH(Fecha),'/',YEAR(Fecha),' ',SUBSTRING('(Fecha))',CHARINDEX(' ','2018-10-05 12:46:03.000'),9))) AS Fecha"))

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo bien el resultado al que quieres llegar pero, intenta cambiando lo que tienes dentro de la linea raw que tienes por esta

```
(CONCAT(DAY(Fecha),'/',MONTH(Fecha),'/',YEAR(Fecha), ' ', Convert(Varchar, Fecha, 108))) As Fecha
```

o esta

```
(Concat(Convert(Varchar, Fecha, 103), ' ', Convert(Varchar, Fecha, 108))) As Fecha
```